# Read a text file in C++, saving data to integers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, text-files

I'm trying to manipulate a text file with similar characteristics as the following.

The objective is to save the data to 4 integers with the corresponding values of 1, 2, 3 and 4, and an array with those 3 columns and 4 lines.

Because the file has other series of %%%, I wanted to understand a way to isolate the next arrays (some with different and unpredictable dimensions) in between those blocks.

Great thanks in advance!

file.txt:

```
file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%            Description           %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
a  b c d
1       2  3        4
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
coord  x  y
    1    0.00000e+00    0.00000e+00
    2    1.00000e+00    0.00000e+00
    3    0.00000e+00    1.00000e+00
    4    2.00000e+00    2.00000e+00
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: What is the comment `%` format ? One at the start of the line mean that the line should not be read ?

Answer (score 0):

Read it line by line. If the line contains a `'%'` then get a [substring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) of the beginning of the line, not including the `'%'` or anything after that. Strip leading and trailing whitespace. If the resulting string is empty it was only comments and nothing else.

The first two non-empty lines are the names and their numbers. The next few non-empty lines are the table header and the actual table.

Comment: From the example, I should rather say that any line starting by `%`is a comment or everything between a `%`  and EOL is a comment, no ?

Comment: @Johan That's what it looks like to me, too.  Which means that having read the line, all you need to do is `line.erase( std::find( line.begin(), line.end(), '%' ), line.end() );`